# AngularJS ignoring set-cookie header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies, cross-domain

I am receiving an http response with a set-cookie header that I can see in Chrome Devloper tools. I can even see the cookie listed under the network header, however the cookie is not being set in the browser. The browser will set same origin cookies but not ones from CORS requests.

I have tried exposing the header, to find out it is forbidden

I have tried setting withCredentials to true and setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true`, I am not using a wildcard for my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and I have the cookie path set to `'/'`

I tried making this POST request with jQuery, but I could still not console log the set cookie header visible in the Chrome Developer Tools:

#### How do I make the browser set this cookie?

Here are some relevant parts of my project (Node/Express backend w/ AngularJS frontend):

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8000'})
app.use(session({
  secret: 'A_SECRET',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    path: '/',
    domain: 'http://localhost:8000',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24
  }
}))
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
  next();
})
```

And in the front end (port 8000) -

```
angular.module('signIn', [
'core.company',
'signUp'
])
  .config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

Sign-in component:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3000/login',
    data: self.user
}).then(function successCallback(response, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(response.headers('Set-Cookie'))  // logs null
    console.log(response.headers('set-cookie'))  // logs null
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    return response
});
```

Comment: So you can see the `Set-Cookie` coming through successfully, but checking cookies in devtools -> application -> cookies shows that they do not actually get set. Correct? I am having the same issue. Were you able to find the answer?

Comment: Hey so I essentially had to give up on this. I could see the cookies in devtools but they were not actually setting when you click the i in the top left corner of the browser. Instead I found out that I can reference the session ID passport provides using `req.sessionid` and then I sent that back as a part of my http response. I then used AngularJS's `ng-Cookie` to create a cookie on the front end using the session ID I sent it. It's a workaround for sure, but it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like my problem was `withCredentials` was set the wrong way. Curious though, what do you mean "the i in the top left corner of the browser?" I'm not seeing anything like that that would show cookies.

Comment: Well I was using localhost so there's no SSL/TLS certificate installed so Chrome just shows a little "i" wrapped in a circle to the left of your URL. For https sites this is a green padlock that says "secure" or the name of the company depending on their certificate. If you click this "i" or green lock Chrome will show you the cookies in use.